# Reversing strings in an array with Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I am looking to reverse an array of strings.  For example the original array would look like this

```
var array = ["lizard", "Rhino", "Monkey"]
```

and the end result should be those words reversed in the same order like this remaining in one array:

```
["drazil", "onihR", "yeknoM"]
```

what I have now is this and I am reversing the strings correctly however it is making 3 separate arrays and all of the strings are separated by commas.

```
var array = ["lizard", "Rhino", "Monkey"]

for index in (array) {
  println(reverse(index))
}

[d, r, a, z, i, l]
[o, n, i, h, R]
[y, e, k, n, o, M]
```

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shorter way is to map the array of strings and reverse the characters and then initialize a String from them.

Swift 2.0:

```
let array = ["lizard", "Rhino", "Monkey"]
let reversed = array.map() { String($0.characters.reverse()) }
print(reversed) // [drazil, onihR, yeknoM]
```

Swift 1.2:

```
let array = ["lizard", "Rhino", "Monkey"]
let reversed = array.map() { String(reverse($0)) }
print(reversed) // [drazil, onihR, yeknoM]
```

Answer (score 3):

For swift 3.0

```
func reverseAString(value :String) -> String {
    //value
    return  (String(value.characters.reversed()))
}
```

Thats It!!